# Google Places API key - The provided API key is invalid

Tags: api, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to set up a routine to get some data from the Google Places API. I followed the instructions here: [Google](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=de) and requested an api key.

When I'm trying to receive some information through my web browser I get the following error message: "The provided API key is invalid."

On the API console under 'Dashboard' there is an entry named 
'Google Places API Web Service'.

Please help, I have no idea why I get this response from the api...

Comment: Please add here your javascript code Snippet

Comment: There's no code I'm trying to get the information through my web browser. That's possible right?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly ?

Comment: I'm just pasting a link like this to the address bar: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=myapikey?location=some_coordinates?radius=750

Comment: So you have an API key, but it's invalid? Have you requested a new one or checked its validity?

Comment: I have requested three keys so far

Comment: Can you give me the details of the query you are passing to the URL? I ll update my answer when you do

Comment: Two answers above: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=myapikey?location=some_coordinates?radius=750 Or do need you need some more information? EDIT: here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) for the places api

Comment: I have just responded below. The issue is not just the API validation but how you use URL-encoding. **Take a look at my answer**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you URL-encode your query is not correct.

My query: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=MY_KEY&location=41.3851,%202.1734&radius=750

Returns the following response:

```
 {
 "html_attributions" : [],
 "next_page_token" : "CpQCDwEAAJttcEn3BV8j9t-k-
  nxrwZ_ZcPaIK6Am17AlBzr1GbRDtfNa0jWA__st6OoMF1XuaLEhRns1Crd-
  IdRHg5Nt2_kjaPS25f-
  nYVrOxgzZwnDUn8_2_RpTfRTG3ri_QwmpwdGEmFJ6wkHp4qHIlsd4hfYe-
  6Uzm8_yxEhp9bvY8eC7YvBHW3DKyldx5WTGip0Xa2xdBZ-
  O78rt_Ourr0mwXHPumixsiMgwuJe3hyKj9FjbG-J1PId5T6-
  u1ApmR599_wT2l7B47xDcSWsW5efZgrUFR-



4FeIkxmMmDZhlijaHwvcdasFSEXDbZsjPDg4C08v2WEdhsm7bCZjFdlCpCLcjlLPfW3vGN8Z0-
37Pk4xGVEhBqIEy2LGaOBDW6dxNOFMoZGhR3d9diXuJ64VDfHxexhWldtG-oZg",
 "results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 41.38506389999999,
           "lng" : 2.1734035
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 41.4695761,
              "lng" : 2.2280099
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 41.320004,
              "lng" : 2.0695258
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
     "id" : "5695851cee37adbcea7305c0473a15906dbcab8f",
     "name" : "Barcelona",
     "photos" : [
```

Etc, etc.

Read this article on URL-encoding and change the `?` in your string leaving only one after `json`

Comment: That's it! I used a `?` symbol for concatenating all the parameters instead of `&`. Thank you!

Comment: Yes ! Indeed. Can you **accept my answer** please? Just click the green button. thank you !

Comment: so my answer solves the issue and it still gets down-voted? That is a murky way of doing business.

Comment: I tried to vote it up, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Sorry bout that ;)

Comment: You just need to accept my answer as valid not up-voting. The **green tick**. If you cannot do that, never mind...

Comment: Alright alright, keep cool. It wasn't green though ;)

Comment: I am cool like a cucumber mate ! :) thank you